# icon not showing at live server

Tags: php, css, icons

Im using icon resources from fontawesome. All of my icon is not show. I checked my source link of icon and it is same with my local. My icon on local work but on live server didnt work. Is there any solution on my problem?

Comment: i would guess a path issue - what's the url to the live server?

Comment: the url of the live server I already follow the server url

Answer (score -1):

Most probably a CORS (Cross Origin Request) issue.

If your website is loaded over https and the font file from fontawesome called over http (or the otherway around, or from a subdomain) it will not load the font, ergo, not load the icons.

Fastest way to test this is using a CDN to load fontawesome fonts and looking for the resources tab in the devtools console.

The console should also show a warning about not loading fonts due to Cross Origin headers not present in the resource.

Comment: im sorry Im afraid that I didnt understand about CORS. How should I know about it. And how can I check it using devtools console? I am very new, sorry for asking much

Comment: If you're using chrome, just press F12 and reload the page, It will show the rendered page html source and some warnings in the bottom. CORS basically means you can't use stuff "unsafe" from other places. So it thinks that your site and the site you're pulling the font off is not the same. As i said, try using a CDN to load fontawesome and it should work.

Comment: I look over the console, and it have a warning
jquery-1.11.1.js:9592 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.